# Alt Click to Rotate View + Loop Select

Tags: shortcut

I've found that I can't set Alt + Left Click to both Rotate Viewport AND keep Loop Select. Rotate View works in Object Mode, but in Edit Mode Alt Select only works for Loop Select.

Is there a way to make them both work at the same time? If I'm clicking in empty space it should do Rotate View, and it should only Loop Select if I'm clicking on an edge

Using Blender 2.77

Thanks

Comment: I don't think Blender is as smart as Zbrush or other software where hotkeys are context sensitive on what is under cursor.

Comment: The default behaviour of Blender for loop selecting is `Alt`+`Right Mouse Button`. I think it's best to use one shortcut for loop selecting and another for rotating the view because, after all, you may want to rotate view when mouse cursor is over an edge loop not only over empty space.

Comment: Thanks @MrZak and @Jerryno yeah I've set it to `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Left` for the time being, I think that will probably have to do